# Sort Delicious bookmarks from all users by popularity

Tags: bookmarks, delicious, sorting

When on the Delicious homepage there is the **hotlist > popular** bookmarks. This only shows very few bookmarks. Doesn't seem to be actually tagged bookmarks ranked by number of times saved by different delicious users. That's what I'm searching for.

On a normal tag search you can only change number of shown links in display options. In Delicious forums this *bug* is often mentioned too.

Is there a hack that makes this possible?